# Check all my checkboxes in my table with knockout

Tags: css, knockout.js

I have a table with checkboxes in the first col. In the heading I also have a checkbox. This one when clicked should check all checkboxes in my table.

```
<table class="defaultGrid">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: model.Things">
    <tr data-bind="css: {selected: IsSelected}">
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected" /></td>
        <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jJ4H6/29/

How to accomplish this with knockout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a function which goes through all of the items in the `Things` collection and set the `IsSelected` to true or false.

Then you can bind this function on the "main" checkbox click:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: selectAll"/>
```

An example implementation would look like this:

```
self.selectAll = function(data, event)
{
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.model.Things (), function(item){
       if (event.target.checked)
          item.IsSelected(true);
       else
          item.IsSelected(false);
    });
    return true; //to trigger the browser default bahaviour
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YFkBQ/).

Or you can have an `IsAllSelected` property on your viewmodel and use the `checked` binding instead of the click and do the selection logic inside the change event of the  `IsAllSelected` (or you can also use a writable computed observable) .

I think eventually you will need something like this if you want to support scenarios like: select all -> unchecking each row by hand should uncheck the header row etc.

[Another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eTF2S/) using an `IsAllSelected` computed property

```
self.IsAllSelected = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var isAllSelected = true;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.model.Things(), function (item) {
                isAllSelected = isAllSelected && item.IsSelected()
            });
            return isAllSelected;
        },
        write: function (value) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.model.Things(), function (item) {
                if (value) item.IsSelected(true);
                else item.IsSelected(false);
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. Your second solution is the best for my purpose.